# DISCORD.JS how to purge delete messages?

Tags: javascript, discord

I can't seem to figure out how to delete messages in a channel with a specified amount. ex: p.command 15. deletes 15 messages.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad and StackOverflow isn't a free coding service either, if you have attempted to solve this issue yourself, it would be of benefit if you could post your code. Alternatively, I recommend you take a look at the discord.js documentation here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you mean a sort of purge command.

```
let messagecount = parseInt(numberofmessages);
message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: messagecount })
  .then(messages => message.channel.bulkDelete(messages));
```

`numberofmessages` is the number of messages you want to delete. You can replace it with another variable or argument.